# text background color in RTF

Tags: html, ios, converters, rtf

For some reasons, I need to export RTF data (no images, text-only) from an iOS application to be able to read it in Word or any word processor. For now, this export creates a RTF file that can be read in TextEdit or Word (MacOS & Windows), showing the background color of the original text. Both can read and display correctly the text as it was displayed on the iPhone UIWebView.

But unfortunately, when trying to read this RTF as an input to my iPhone application (and as a quick look provided by iOS in email application), the text color is OK but the background color doesn't display.

When analyzing the HTML created by UIWebView after importing this exported RTF data, I can see that no information about text background color has been kept by iOS's import feature (that is quite logical since the same background color is not displayed by "quick look" feature in iOS email application).

After hours spent to analyze Word RTF version of a document, I couldn't find the good way to code my RTF for background color compatibility. RTF specification speaks about \cbN to put background color to the Nth color of the color table. As Word doesn't implement this \cbN control, I implemented the \chcfpat0\chcbpatN\cbN control to keep compatibility with MacOS TextEdit and Word software (any platform). And it works. But the RTF import tool in iOS neither recognize \chcfpat0\chcbpatN nor \cbN keywords.

Does anybody has any magic idea to deal with that silly problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried "\highlightN" where N is the color value?

Comment: Thanks for your message. I tried, and it has no result also.

Answer (score 1):

I always use WordPad when trying to create simple RTF-formatted documents. Most of the time, I'm trying to display formatted text in a WinForms application, and need something that the [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control can handle being assigned to its [Rtf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter.

WordPad calls the background color the "text highlight color".

I just used this to display some rich-text in a [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control with a black background-color. I set the text-highlight-color to black, and the text-color to white, inside WordPad, saved the document, opened the document in Notepad, copied the raw RTF text from there, and assigned it to the [Rtf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, and it worked fine.

Hopefully this technique will work in your situation.